# some advice needed: xampp / git / openshift

Tags: git, openshift

I've developed a PHP app with CodeIgniter, on a local xampp setup (php, mySQL, mercury) and am now trying to deploy it to an OpenShift gear.

The local xampp app setup is ok, the openshift setup is ok, and the git setup is almost ok.

The more I try to achieve my objective, the more complex it seems to get.

It seems that the openshift php cartridge has a different folder structure to the xampp htdocs/application/... structure.

So my attempts to push a git repository is pointless, until I've either done some fancy configurations to send the right files to the right folders, OR, I've scrapped xampp and switched to Apache / mySQL proper, which will then match the openshift gear.

Am I missing something, or is there a simple solution? I'd appreciate some guidance and advice. Thanks in advance.

---

My local xampp installation has htdocs with 3 applications, each inside of it's own folder, in the htdocs directory.

The OpenShift equivalent of htdocs is php and inside is the application. For three applications, each application has it's own git repo.

So I cannot simply change my DocumentRoot, from htdocs to php because (a) there is already a php directory - the php codebase which will then get pushed, and (b) I will be pushing all apps (in my case 3) to openshift, when I only want to push 1.

So I'm thinking the only real "clean" way is to run my git repo interactions outside of my xampp installation entirely.

(1) setup openshift application, 
(2) clone the remote repository to my local machine (inside c:\gitrepos) and then
(3) copy and paste my whole app (only one app) code from htdocs to this staging area in gitrepos, and then 
(4) do the whole commit/push etc to deploy.

Sounds solid enough to me, although a bit laborious....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I would modify XAMP DocumentRoot to point to your php directory from your git repo.  That will fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks gshipley, I've edited my original question in response, but I don't think that'll solve my problem...?